# Can I shorten casts?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

is it possible to create a function to shorten casts, like (pseudocode):

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mytag");
//shorten:
findByTag(MyFragment.class, "mytag");


private Fragment findByTag(Class<?> cast, String tag) {
    return (cast) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code as following:

```
private <F extends Fragment> F findByTag(Class<F> cast, String tag) {
    return (F) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

Now you can call it without casting:

```
MyFragment f1 = findByTag(MyFragment.class, "aaaaa");
YourFragment f2 = findByTag(YourFragment.class, "bbbbb");
```

Comment: This gives you a warning and may lead to a `ClassCastException` somewhere else. Using `cast.cast(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag))` is better as it throws immediately in case of a problem.